# How to pass a macro in externalized tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzscale

I experience a problem when I use `tikzscale` package to compile figures externally.

The minimal working environment is as follows.

The main.tex:

```
\documentclass[\myopts]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,backgrounds,calc,patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{er}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usepgflibrary{shapes.geometric}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figure-build/]

% Use the package ifpdf to share one test document between pdflatex and latex
\usepackage{ifpdf}

\ifpdf
\else
    \tikzset{external/system call={latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource"; dvips -E -o "\image".eps "\image".dvi; ps2pdf "\image".eps "\image".pdf;}}
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[bth]
    \includegraphics[height=3.25in,width=5.25in]{FileDef-Fig}
    \caption{\small {text}}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

The content of the file FileDef-Fig.tikz looks like:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
........
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I compile this `main.tex` file by

```
pdflatex --shell-escape "\def\myopts{"conference,10pt"}\input{main}"
```

However, this command complains that the macro `\myopts` can not be found in the log file.

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \myopts
```

This error message is reported in the following command when the figure is compiled by an automatically generated command:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape \
         -halt-on-error \
         -interaction=batchmode \
         -jobname "figure-build/main-figure0" \
  "\def\tikzexternalrealjob{main} \input{main}"
```

My question is how to add a `\def\myopts{...}` in the above `pdflatex` command to make it looks like:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape \
         -halt-on-error \
         -interaction=batchmode \
         -jobname "figure-build/main-figure0" \
  "\def\myopts{...} \def\tikzexternalrealjob{main} \input{main}".
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking... perhaps you should walk through the `tikzscale` documentation as a starting point (with `texdoc tikzscale`) and make sure you're not missing a step.  I'm sorry I'm not more familiar with the package :( but I'm sure someone else is.

Comment: Does `tikzscale` itself externalize TikZ pictures? The `external` library is actually used to `pdflatex` the document again, you can insert `\def\opts{…}` here too if it setup correctly. Can you [edit](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/126746/edit) your question to include a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `\myopts` for external `system call`, too.

Add `\string\def\string\myopts{\myopts}` in front of `\texsource`.

The `\string` writes the macros `\def` and `\myopts` as they are without expanding them (or trying to). The second `\myopts` should be expanded, of course.

(By the way, I have used

```
pdflatex --shell-escape "\def\myopts{conference,10pt}\input{<file name>}"
```

without the extra `"` in the `\myopts` definition.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[\myopts]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=figure-build/]

% Use the package ifpdf to share one test document between pdflatex and latex
\usepackage{ifpdf}

\ifpdf
  \tikzset{external/system call={%
    pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode
      -jobname "\image" "\string\def\string\myopts{\myopts}\texsource"}}
\else
  \tikzset{external/system call={%
    latex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode
      -jobname "\image" "\string\def\string\myopts{\myopts}\texsource";
      dvips -E -o "\image".eps "\image".dvi; ps2pdf "\image".eps "\image".pdf;}}
\fi

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}[bth]
    \includegraphics[height=3.25in,width=5.25in]{FileDef-Fig}
    \caption{\small {text}}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. It worked. Another question appears. The externally compiled tikz figures are not rebuilt after modifications. I have to manually remove the .dep, .dpth, .log, .table, and .pdf files. Then, a .pdf file is rebuilt. How to deal with the issue of making tikz externalization to automatically rebuild figures after modifications are made?