# Compile with TikZ external library

Tags: tikz-pgf, xetex, texworks

As explained in the `pgf` manual under 32.4 and in various other questions/comments here on TeX.sX (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/44508/9077, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/32363/9077, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23565/9077), it's possible to export a TikZ picture as a pdf with document like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
% main document, called main.tex
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize % activate!
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {root}
child {node {left}}
child {node {right}
child {node {child}}
child {node {child}}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem, however, is that neither the manual nor these answers provide any detailed explanation for how to compile this document. I'm using texlive in Windows 7 with TeXworks, so please do not suggest command line compilation procedures.

I need to compile with XeLaTeX since I'm using `fontspec`. My XeLaTeX compilations look like the following:

[image]

[image]

What do I need to change to be able to use the external TikZ library?

Comment: You need `--shell-escape` active.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Yes, the manual and the questions I link to say something of that sort, but I have tried to add ``--shell-escape`` in various places, but it never works. Could you (or someone) please provide a complete compilation procedure for XeLaTeX?

Comment: `xelatex --shell-escape --synctex <filename>` should do. However, you also need to setup `external` to use XeLaTeX, especially if the preamble uses XeLaTeX-specific stuff, the [`/tikz/external/system call`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126858/16595) needs to be setup correctly.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel 1. The inclusion of ``<filename>`` there indicates to me that this is a command line interface? I don't use the command line, so I wondering (as indicated in my question) what I need to include in TeXworks compilation. 2. I'm sure I need to set up ``external`` correctly, but I have no idea how to do that ...

Comment: Well, TeXworks doesn’t do anything but to use that command sent to the system/shell/whatever. Can’t you use the `+` button and add `--shell-escape` to the options? I don’t know about `latexmk` but it probably has also an option to use the compiler with `--shell-escape`.

Comment: Yes, but ``<filename>``? If I need to add the name of my file here every time I compile, then the compilation is not automatic anymore, which I believe is the point of this feature in TeXworks. But this wouldn't matter much in the end if it won't compile anyway without me having set up ``external`` "correctly" first ...

Comment: Isn’t that covered by `$fullname`?

Comment: I have no idea, since I don't know what ``$fullname`` means. The reason I am asking how to modify these TeXworks compilations is that I don't have much knowledge of these things. If I did, I presumably would have figured out how to do this on my own. What about the "correct" setup for ``external``?

Comment: @Sverre have you successfully set up `--shell-escape` in TeXworks by now? Or is this still an open issue?

Comment: @PaulGessler This is still an open issue.

Comment: @Sverre what problems are you having?

Comment: @PaulGessler: Nothing has changed since I wrote the original question. So the problem is "that neither the manual nor these answers provide any detailed explanation for how to compile this document".

Comment: @Sverre please see here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82699/how-to-enable-shell-escape-in-texworks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Paul Gessler's link to [How to enable shell-escape in TeXworks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82699/how-to-enable-shell-escape-in-texworks), `--shell-escape` can be added to the `XeLaTeX` compilation in `TeXworks` like this:

[image]

Running the `MWE` in the original question, the compiler will compile a separate file `main-figure0.pdf` with only the `TikZ` figure, in addition to the full document `main.pdf`:

[image]